# How to use eval() to assign one object to another

Tags: javascript, eval

Disclaimer: I know you are supposed to not use `eval()` but I wouldn't if I had any other choice in my situation. This, you must trust.

Why does this code below throw a error and how can I make an equivalent expression?

```js
let r = ".b.b = a.b.b"
let l = {b:{b:5}}
let a = {b:{b:0}}
l.toString()
alert(eval(l+r))
```

Comment: What error does it throw? Might it have something to do with the missing `;`?

Comment: "this you must trust" - no I do not. In my experience, in almost all cases where someone says "I need eval", it turns out it's an XY problem, better solved without it. What is the exact scenario you need this for?

Comment: I am using two contexts meaning using two window objects to communicate with one another using the message channel and I am making a game and the game runs on the main thread while the viewport on the child thread and when I click on the UI I want to assign one objects child to another and this is where the eval comes in

Comment: Even if you had to use `eval`, I'm not clear on what this code is attempting to accomplish. What is your expected output?

Comment: eval exists and is fully supported by the language so don't get fooled by babysitters: you are totally allowed and supposed to use it.

Comment: I have a child object that is is nested in a object that is part of an array like array[Id] = theParent , so I want "theParent.children[otherobjchild] = otherParent.children[otherobjchild] " and this on my main gives me a "invalid or unexpected token" error

Comment: @EricMORAND doesn't the same hod true for `goto` in other languages? It exists, therefore you are supposed to use it. In reality `eval` *is* needed some times. However, when it's not it's better avoided - at the very least, it makes code harder to refactor, possibly harder to understand exactly and harder to optimise.

Comment: The error message *"invalid or unexpected token"* signals a syntax error i.e. your code does not compile correctly. Using `eval()` won't fix it.

Comment: I still don't get why `theParent.children[otherobjchild] = otherParent.children[otherobjchild]` requires `eval`. @EricMORAND MDN even has a large section on ["Do not ever use `eval`"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!). I don't believe "ever" is warranted; but it is _almost_ never the best choice.

Comment: @Amadan I agree, the heading of that section is too harsh. Especially since before that it talks about a useful case for eval - if you have some arithmetic expression built up as a string. Assuming you have dynamically acquired numbers and operators, you can just `eval` them. The alternative is to manually parse the string and build up the expression evaluation yourself - e.g., something like `add(5); add(3); multiply(2)` for `(5 + 3) * 2`. However, that would require doing an entirely new parsing functionality where doing `eval("(5 + 3) * 2")` requires nothing.

Comment: @Amadan I figured out my issue it was just that I had previously put the Id in the square brackets and it was supposed to be a string. Also I need eval() due to the usage of the function I am using . It takes the string and runs it straight up as is the useage of eval. It is meant to mimic the code being in the same thread and to make sure I don't have to make a sender and receiver every time I want to communicate a command .

Comment: @EricMORAND Guns exist, and you're allowed to use them.  That doesn't mean they aren't dangerous if you use them wrong.

Comment: @Amadan but it's not MDN responsibility to make that decision. Saying eval should never be used is as stupid as saying "==" should never been used. Most of the time, this will not give the expected result but that kind of warning is basically babysitting and assume developers don't know what they are doing.

Comment: @EricMORAND You are overreacting to a title. I did say "ever" is an exaggeration. But the article below is not prescriptive, it lays out many reasons why `evil` is suboptimal in the majority of situations, and is written precisely to inform developers who do not know what they are doing what the better alternatives are in the many situations one might be tempted to use it. And if you insist on continuing to use it _in contexts where it is demonstrably slower, less legible and/or less safe than alternatives_, real babysitting with a more experienced code reviewer might actually be warranted.

Comment: @Amadan my point is that when someone come here asking for some help with eval, he needs to explain that he knows what he is doing and that is use it on purpose. This is becoming crazy and super annoying. To the point where bundler like Rollup throws warning if the find eval in your code. Seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that is causing you an error is that your `l.toString()` call is returning the string `"[Object object]"`.

Try using `l = JSON.stringify(l)` instead.

Although, to make your code snippet work, you need to omit stringifying `l` altogether. Instead reference `l` as just the string `"l"` to make the eval work as expected.

```js
let r = ".b.b = a.b.b"
let l = {b:{b:5}}
let a = {b:{b:0}}
console.log(eval("l"+r))
```

Comment: How is `eval('l.b.b = a.b.b')` better than `l.b.b = a.b.b`?

Comment: To be honest, I would prefer the latter, however his question was specifically how to make this eval code work. Maybe he has a unique use case?

Comment: @AndrewSteinheiser pretty much everyone who elects to use `eval` claims to have a unique case, and almost all the time that's not the case. In fact, the time, the legit uses of `eval` I've mostly seen *suggested* to somebody who was trying to find a solution without mentioning `eval`.

Comment: I understand you should generally not use `eval()` and most cases can be solved without it, however, it's not impossible. I had a use case for it not too long ago. We wanted to be able to enter small javascript snippets (i.e. `if(x>2){return 5}else{return x*2}`) for a dynamic, unique calculation per item.

Comment: @vlaz, and how would you interpret javascript code, like a pre-compiled template, without eval? I have another point of view: pretty much everyone who elects to use eval claims to have a unique case, and almost all the time that's exactly the case.

Comment: @EricMORAND like the many a person who can't figure out bracket notation? Because a lot of the cases I see are those and that's not very unique. As for pre-compiled JS code - a lot of times, you don't need to be passing around JS code, you can generate the appropriate logic from input. Not always, of course but you know - I already explained that. If I do it again, I fear you are just going try suggest again that as if I've somehow said you should absolutely never, ever use it at all. As has been pointed out, you are indeed overreacting.

Comment: @EricMORAND: "how would you interpret javascript code, like a pre-compiled template, without eval?" If you'd read the article I linked, `Function` is equally insecure, equally powerful, but does not destroy cache, does not kill compilation benefits, does not break under minification. In many years on Stack Overflow, I still haven't seen a credible case for `eval` in JS. And (no offense to OP) if someone can't figure out `[object Object]` issue, I don't trust their case will be unique enough to be the first in my experience to actually need `eval`.